# How to change emphasis commands in pandoc's LaTeX template?

Tags: conversion, emphasis, pandoc

I want to change the default **strong** emphasis command in the conversion from pandoc's markdown to LaTeX, say, from `\textbf` to `\textsc`. Since running pandoc in the source file prints into the `.tex` file `\textbf`, I think it has nothing to do with the chosen template (unless the latter redefines `\textbf`, but that doesn't seem like a good option). I wish to tell pandoc to convert its strong emphasis into a `\strong` LaTeX command that I can define in the LaTeX template.

Comment: This seems like a perfect case for a Pandoc filter or script (see: <http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html>). I think it should be relatively easy, but I'm too much of a Haskell noob to write it. I've posted a query to the Pandoc discussion list, and will post an answer here if one is forthcoming.

Comment: @PaulM. I decided to try here first, just in case it was something simple... Thank you for posting in the pandoc discussion list, I saw that there's already an answer there, and it worked for me (despite a warning). Please, post that answer so I can vote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A query on the Pandoc discussion list](http://groups.google.com/group/pandoc-discuss/t/3febaae8c2aee753) yielded a couple of nice responses, from Andrea Rossato and John MacFarlane (developer of Pandoc). Below I give John's answer. This assumes you have the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) installed.

1. Assume this is your Pandoc file, `myexample.md`

   ```
   A *simple* pandoc example with **strong emphasis**!
   ```
2. The following Haskell program exploits Pandoc's scripting interface

   ```hs
   -- strongify.hs
   -- compile as 'ghc --make strongify.hs'

   import Text.Pandoc

   main = toJsonFilter makeItStrong
      where makeItStrong (Strong xs) = [latex "\\strong{"] ++ xs ++ [latex "}"]
            makeItStrong x           = [x]
            latex                    = RawInline "latex"
   ```
3. Compile the program:

   ```
   ghc --make strongify.hs
   ```
4. You can then use the generated executable as so:

   ```
   pandoc -t json myexample.md | ./strongify | pandoc -f json -t latex
   ```
5. The output of step 4 is:

   ```
   A \emph{simple} pandoc example with \strong{strong emphasis}!
   ```

John MacFarlane makes the following point:

> "...the advantage of this
>   approach over postprocessing the output with sed or perl:  "\textbf" in
>   verbatim environments won't be touched."

Comment: For the sake of completeness, when using csquotes in the template, running `pandoc -t json ...` loses smart quotes and punctuation, so one must add the `-S` option.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of future discoverers of this thread, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472828/unable-to-compile-haskell-program-couldnt-match-errors, in which John explains subsequent changes to pandoc causes strongify.hs to throw an error.

This works under 1.15.0.6

```
-- strongify.hs
-- compile as 'ghc --make strongify.hs'

import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter makeItStrong
   where makeItStrong (Strong xs) = [latex "\\strong{"] ++ xs ++ [latex "}"]
         makeItStrong x           = [x]
         latex                    = RawInline (Format "latex")
```